# how to subscribe/publish to topics in ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Somebody can tell me how to subscribe/publish to topics in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32301/how-to-subscribe/publish-to-topics-in-ros?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-04-20

Post score: -10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps by reading the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials), helpfully linked from the very front page of ros.org?

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10